# Check if an element is an array using recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I would like to check if an element inside an array is another array. I'm solving a code challenge where the problem is iterating through an array and checking for a 7 but if an
element is an array I would like to continuously check each nested array for a 7.

I have console.log() in my first 'if' statement and I've seen that sevenBoom() is being called more than once. But for some reason it's not returning 'Boom!'

SevenBoom should return 'Boom!' if there's a seven.

```
    function sevenBoom(arr) {
      if (arr.includes(7)) {
        return "Boom!";
      }
    
      arr.forEach((val) => {
        if (Array.isArray(val)) sevenBoom(val);
      });
    }

    sevenBoom([1, 3, 4, 6, [7]) // Returns undefined
    sevenBoom([3, 7, 8, 9]) // Returns 'Boom!'
```

Comment: Can you add some example input as an [mcve] to your question.

Comment: `sevenBoom` is returning something; so why do you ignore the return value inside the `forEach`? Why are you using `forEach` which will ignore a return value anyway? Use [`some`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead.

Comment: Or just do flat(), but your issue is the fact you never return from the forEach and the forEach is really the wrong thing to use in this situation.

Comment: what return value do you expect fro arrays not having a `7` value?

Comment: @NinaScholz Oh I'm just going to add an else statement, returning a string with "There is no 7". That's all.

Comment: `nums.flat(Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY).includes(7)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If 7 is not present in the root array, then your function isn't returning anything.
Try this, just a minor refactoring:

```
function sevenBoom(arr) {
    if (arr.includes(7)) return 'Boom!';

    for (let val of arr) {
      if (Array.isArray(val)) {
        if (sevenBoom(val)) return sevenBoom(val);
      }
    }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I'm working on other problems and I'm staring at them a little too long, and I realize I'm going brain dead looking at SO recursion answers. I knew I overlooked something. My forEach was a horrible choice, smh . Thanks again.

Comment: Note: this won't work on `[1, [5, 4], 3, 5, [7]]`.

Comment: yeah right, it wont, i have the edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 3):

You could take a boolean value as result and use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for checking arrays.

```js
function hasSeven(array) {
    function seven(a) {
        return a.includes(7) || a.some(v => Array.isArray(v) && seven(v));
    }
    return seven(array)
        ? 'Boom!'
        : 'There is no 7';
}


console.log(hasSeven([7]));
console.log(hasSeven([[7]]));
console.log(hasSeven([[[7]]]));

console.log(hasSeven([]));
console.log(hasSeven([[]]));
console.log(hasSeven([[[]]]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sevenBoom = (arr) => {
  const recurse = (arr) => arr.some(n => Array.isArray(n) ? recurse(n) : n === 7);

  if (recurse(arr)) {
    return 'Boom';
  }
}
```

This is assuming what should be returned other than 'Boom' is `void`. It's a bit of an awkward place for recursion since you want to return a string if you meet some criteria and nothing otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to return the value from your second if condition too.

But `forEach()` cannot be interrupted (for ex: with a return statement) and will run for all items. So you can keep track using a flag variable outside the `forEach()` and return your result on that basis.

```js
  function sevenBoom(arr) {
      if (arr.includes(7)) {
        return "Boom!";
      }
       let found = false;
      arr.forEach((val) => {
        if (Array.isArray(val))                          if(sevenBoom(val)) found="Boom!"; 
      })
    return found;
}
    
    console.log(sevenBoom([1,2,3]));
    console.log(sevenBoom([1,2,7]));
    console.log(sevenBoom([1,2,[2,7]]));
    console.log(sevenBoom([1,2,[2,3,[4,5]]]));
    console.log(sevenBoom([1,2,[2,3,[4,7]]]));
```

Note: How `sevenBoom()` can be directly used inside an if statement. This is because of the concept of [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values.

PS: As mentioned above, `forEach()` will run for all items, no matter what. You can use any other looping mechanism like a simple `for loop`, `some()` etc. I just copied your code and hence used `forEach()`

Comment: Why continue to check after it is found?

Comment: Just wanted to update on the code OP had written. Didn't change the looping mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if an element is seven in the same loop that you are checking if an element is an array that way you can avoid going through the array unnecessarily.

```
const sevenBoom = arr => {
    for (const ele of arr) {
        if (ele === 7) return 'Boom';

        if (Array.isArray(ele)) {
            //this prevents you from halting your function early
            //you only want to return in the loop if a 7 is found
            if (boom(ele) === 'Boom') return 'boom'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.flat(depth)` method to flatten each array before using the `.includes()` method. Choose a depth that would cover all possible arrays for your project.

```
function sevenBoom(arr) {
    return arr.flat(10).includes(7) ? 'Boom!' : '-'
}
```

**DEMO**

```js
let a = [1, 3, 4, 6, [7]],
    b = [3, 7, 8, 9],
    c = [1,2,[5,6,[3,5,[7,6]]]],
    d = [0],
    e = [1, [5, 4], 3, 5, [7]];

function sevenBoom(arr) {
    return arr.flat(10).includes(7) ? 'Boom!' : '-'
}

for(let arr of [a,b,c,d,e]) {
    console.log( sevenBoom( arr ) );
}

console.log( e ); //Original array remains unchanged
```